# Laravel transaction saves data into DB even when it's rollbacked

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, transactions

I send a request, trying to save multiple documents at once.

Here is my code

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    foreach ($request->documents as $index => $documentInfo) {
        // Check
        if (// some statement) {

            $documentExists = Document::where([
                // some checks
            ])
            ->exists();

            if ($documentExists) {
                throw new \Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
            }
        }


        // Assign document properties

        $document->save(); 
    }

    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false, 
            'document' => $index,
            'message' => '// message',
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', '// message');
}
```

The thing that happens is that I check every document for its own unique values. If two documents with same values try to get saved I want to return an error.
I tried uploading two documents with the same values, the error is returned on the second document and the transaction must fail, but the first document gets saved into the database. 
I don't want this, if there is an error I don't want any documents saved into the DB.

Comment: The first document gets saved because you don't make into your guard `if ($documentExists) {`, as a result no exception is thrown. You may want to create a temporary data structure so you can validate before persisting.

Comment: Based on the provided example, any exception thrown should roll back the entire transaction.  Are you sure your current database engine supports transactions?  For example, InnoDB does while MyISAM does not.

Comment: @matticustard yes I am sure because other transactions in my application work perfectly fine. The engine is InnoDB

Comment: I don't see any errors with your code, which would lead me to believe the problem is elsewhere.  Are you sure you haven't gotten your routes or methods mixed up?  Can you post the whole method instead of just the transaction?  Have you tried adding a `Log::debug(...);` entry to the transaction to see if it's firing twice?